# Quarkus "multiple handles classes" failure from abstract class in jar

Tags: quarkus

I have a utility jar file that contains an abstract class which "implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse>". Essentially it's used for catching exceptions and adding the message id:s to the BatchItemFailure list. However, when trying to use it with the quarkus-amazon-lambda-http extension I end up with a "Multiple handler classes. You have a custom handler class and the AWS Lambda HTTP extension. Please remove one of them from your deployment". Is there any way of ignoring this abstract class in the scanning?

Tried using

```
quarkus.arc.exclude-dependency.common.group-id=my-common-group-id
quarkus.arc.exclude-dependency.common.artifact-id=my-common-artifact-id
```

and

```
quarkus.arc.exclude-types=package-with-wildcard
```

but no go